# US horsemen use the terms "green broke," "cold back(ed)," and "proud cut." Where are these terms used and where did they come from?

Tags: etymology

Here in Southwest Virginia I have heard **cold back** for what others call **green broke.** The only time I have heard **proud cut** is in a Western version of the Child Ballad, Black Jack Davie:

"Way out in old New Mexico

Along the Spanish line...

Go saddle for me the proud cut dunn

With the coal-black mane and tail...

Are these terms used in Australia, Canada or Great Britain? The use of "broke" as a past participle is, I think, archaic, so perhaps **green broke** goes back a long way.

Comment: *horsepeople*?...

Comment: "Proud-cut" [seems fairly common.](https://www.google.com/search?q=proud+cut&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=A5CDWKuTC9PI8Ae2uJz4Cg)

Comment: Sorry, US horsemen? Do you mean ***riders***, specifically ones in the West who work with cattle? Cowboys? This are all highly regional and subject-matter specific terms, as well, as probably being from another time. Are you quoting an older cowboy song?

Comment: @Drew My impression is that the people I'm talking about would not call themselves horsepeople. Consider Horseman Magazine, Eclectic Horseman Magazine, National Horseman (for Saddlebred owners), and Western Horseman (for Western stock horse owners.) For that matter cattlemen don't call themselves cowboys, unless it's midnight.

Comment: @Lambie In the US, all 3 terms are in current use. You can go to horseforum. com for a discussion of the meaning of "green broke, "and as I said I have heard "cold back" here in Southwest VA, Cascabel's link shows that "proud cut" is current. You say these terms are highly regional. You may be right, but I think you are not, which why I want to know if people in Australia, Canada and England use them. There are plenty of riders in both Lexington KY and Lexington VA, but the terms may have migrated from out West or perhaps even from England. The lyrics of the song suggest it came after 1912.

Comment: @Airymouse  They are regional terms or I would have  heard 'em. In US English, most people say riders. Horsemen and horsewoman sound to me like equestrians, the formal term for riders but that would not collocate with the terms you are asking about. I mean do Western riders use the term horseman in everyday speech about riding and horses and breaking in horses??

Comment: I ran an ngram [horseman, horse people, horse rider](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=horseman%2Chorse+people%2C+horse+rider&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Chorseman%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bhorseman%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHorseman%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Chorse%20people%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bhorse%20people%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHorse%20People%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHorse%20people%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Chorse%20rider%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bhorse%20rider%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHorse%20Rider%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHorse%20rider%3B%2Cc0) for AmE, and "horseman" is way more common.

Comment: I was being partly tongue-in-cheek. But is counting uses (ngram) the best way to find the best words to use? Oh, and  do cattlewomen call themselves *cattelemen*? ;-) After midnight too? ;-)

Comment: I'm no horseman but I was interested enough to look up _proud cut_ on the net. In one veterinary article  (THE ‘PROUD-CUT’ GELDING 
Patrick M. McCue 
DVM, PhD) I found the following: _Traditionally, the term ‘proud-cut’ 
implies that a part of the epididymis (sperm 
storage site located adjacent to the testes) 
was left in the horse at the time of castration_. I also came across _cryptorchidism_ or undescended testicle which, looking like gelding, can be miscalled _proud cut_. I now have more knowledge of horse gelding than I ever wanted to posess

Comment: @Drew No. Not after midnight. I talked to a horseman, who was born and raised in Southwest VA. She said that she has been called both horseman and a horse woman, and she's happy with either term. She had not heard "proud cut" but had heard both of the other terms She thought they were more likely to be used by those who rode western style. One more thing: she said that "cold back" was going to supplant "green broke," because people are avoiding talking about breaking in a horse. It just sounds cruel.